# Trying to avoid a modal explosion: if anything can be obligated, and ought-implies-can, then would everything be possible?

Tags: modal-logic, deontic-logic

Where by "anything"/"everything" I mean atomic propositions (and I am quantifying over atomic propositions). The argument would seem to be something like:

1. ◊**OB***A*, ∀<sub>any</sub>*A*
2. **OB***A* → ◊*A*
3. ◊◊*A*
4. (Assuming the superfluity of iterated ◊'s) therefore ◊*A*, ∀<sub>every</sub>*A*

But this would be a modal explosion with respect to the possibility operator, caused by a pre-explosion of the obligation one. **To avoid a modal explosion, then, must I assume that not just anything can be obligated?** Or is this evidence that iterating modal operators is not so superfluous? I realize that we wouldn't usually assume that it was possible for everything to be obligated "at the same time," but we might frown upon trying to rule out some possible individual obligation on such grounds, I think (we'd frown upon trying to show that, per mere logic in general, there must be some *A* that must not be possibly obligatory: c.f. [Fitch's paradox of knowability](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/fitch-paradox/)).

Comment: From an analytic sense: if all of the atomic propositions in your domain of discourse are of a kind that they can be obligated, then it makes sense they they all also have the feature of being possible under the assumption of ought implies can.  I see it more as your set of "everything" only includes those propositions that can be sensibly obligated.

Comment: See [Gayler, Ought Implies Can: Why it is Wrong and How that Impacts Deontic
Logics](https://trace.tennessee.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2797&context=utk_chanhonoproj), especially pp. 21ff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two issues here. One concerns the meaning of 'atomic proposition' and the other is an ambiguity in the sense of 'possible'.

*1. An atomic proposition may be something you take to correspond to an atomic fact, along the lines of the atomism of Russell or early Wittgenstein. I.e. a fact that is fundamental, unanalysable, logically completely independent of all other atomic facts and contingently true or false. If so, there is no theoretical difficulty in saying that all atomic propositions are possible. In effect, this position allows only for logical possibilities and impossibilities.

This kind of logical atomism is not popular. In formal logic, an atomic proposition is just a more or less arbitrarily chosen element of information. In any given formalism, there are sentences that we choose to represent as primitives, without component parts, but this is just a convenience for a particular purpose. It does not entail a metaphysical commitment to such sentences being in principle impossible to analyse into simpler components. It allows that some propositions, despite being represented as atomic, may be logically or metaphysically necessary, or impossible. On this position, it would be incorrect to say that anything is possible, but also incorrect to say that anything is obligatory. Impossible things are not obligatory.

*2. Examples of ought-implies-can often appeal to what is physically impossible. Alice can save Bob or she can save Charlie, but it is physically impossible to do both so she is not obligated to do both. In this sense, it is straightforwardly incorrect to say that anything is possible. If you want to claim that "anything can be obligated" you are suggesting a broader, logical sense of 'can'. Maybe for any given contingent proposition one can imagine a scenario in which it would be obligatory. But it does not follow that it is obligatory within the physical circumstances in which we actually find ourselves. In the language of possible worlds, for any given contingent proposition there is some world where it is obligatory, but in our world physical constraints make some propositions infeasible and hence not obligatory.